# How to simplify my working Python3 regex and make it more Pythonic

Tags: python, regex

I created a working (long) bit of code to check if a file exists in a directory or not and if so to extract two string values and convert them to float.

```
try:
    # use the file name from earlier and append .HDR
    filename = sel_file +'.HDR'

    # open the text file if found, read in the file
    f = open(filename, 'r+')
    data = f.read()
    f.close()

    # these regex are to look for the 2 strings and extracts the values in quotation marks after them
    # the value in quotes is a number written as string. There is only 1 CTRW & several PTR
    c_pat = r'CTRW,\"(.*?)\"'
    p_pat = r'\nPTR,\"(.*?)\"'

    # implements the regex on the file
    c = re.findall(c_pat, data)
    p = re.findall(p_pat, data)

    # for some reason the c & p are saved as lists so this converts to a string and then a float
    ctrw_str = int(float( ''.join(map(str,c))))
    ptr_str = int(float(''.join(map(str,p))))

    # saves to the necessary variable for use later in the code
    CTRW = ctrw_str
    PTR = ptr_str

except IOError:
    # If the file is not in the directory then the following values are used
    CTRW = 120
    PTR = 197
    pass
```

The file is read in as a string but for some unknow reason the regex captures and creates a list, which is not a huge deal but requires the extra step of converting to a string and then a float.

The search for the PTR value returns several within the source file but the the one I want is exactly PTR which is why I used the `\n` for the `p_pat` regex search and not in the `c_pat` regex.

I would like to see if any here have a good idea of how to shrink this into less lines and make it more Pythonic.

Comment: Can you clarify, does the file have multiple instances of `PTR,"123"` ?

Comment: Yes, it is written in the comments: "There is only 1 CTRW & several PTR", but you also mention you need "to extract two string values and convert them to float". Which is true?

Comment: a sample within the larger file that I am looking at has a single instance of  `CTRW,"200"` and a single instance of exactly `PTR,"175.00"` but there are are versions of the string `PTR` located with other characters.  within one text file there are ~11 instances of the string `PTR`, including  `PTR`, `PTRXA`, `PTRXB`, `DNPTR1`, and `TWCPTR`.  I am trying to grab the numbers in quotes so I can use them later within calculations with voltage and current values located in a seperate COMTRADE file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No wonder you get lists, `re.findall` returns a list of found strings.

If - as you say - you want "to extract two string values and convert them to float" use `re.search` to fetch the first match:

```py
try:
    filename = sel_file +'.HDR'
    with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
        data = f.read()
        c = re.search(r'CTRW,"([^"]*)"', data)
        if c:
            CTRW = int(float(c.group(1)))
        p = re.search(r'\nPTR,"([^"]*)"', data)
        if p:
            PTR = int(float(p.group(1)))
except IOError: # If the file is not in the directory then the following values are used
    CTRW = 120
    PTR = 197
    pass
```

Comment: The above worked and definitely looks better than my hacked together version.  Appreciate it.

Comment: @Neil Please kindly upvote the answer if it is helpful.